# Citations and Hyperref

Tags: hyperref, citing

If I introduce a citation in a subsection title I get the following warning:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string
>   (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on
>   input line 18.

This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
    @article{myref,
        author = {author},
        title = {Title},
        journal = {Journal},
        year = {9999},
        volume = {1},
        number = {1},
        pages = {10--20}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Subsection Title \cite{myref} }

  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  \bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: It is prtetty strange to cite something in a structural title.

Comment: That was in fact my second question. If I add introduce method name in a title. Should I only add a reference in the content?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But this is a style question not a TeX question.

Comment: I agree. Sorry and thank you for the feedback. By the way, I sometimes have some "style" questions. What would be an appropriate stackexchange group for that?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're using the `apalike` bibliography style, you should use the field name `journal`, not `journaltitle`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when creating the example. Fixing that now

Answer (score 5):

`\cite` is not expandable and will therefore not work, when the subsection title is expanded to a bookmark string. `\texorpdfstring` can be used to provide an alternative or omit it:

```
\subsection{Subsection Title\texorpdfstring{ \cite{myref}}{}}
```

Or use the optional argument to remove the citation in the table of contents, too.

```
\subsection[Subsection Title]{Subsection Title \cite{myref}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to keep the citation in the title but that it does not appear anywhere else? If I write cite outside the subsection brackets it appears in another line

Comment: @purpleTentacle Use the optional argument of `\subsection` and don't use `\cite` in that optional argument.

Comment: Is there any way of getting the equivalent information automatically e.g. from the `.bbl` Biber generates? I mostly need author and title, possibly year occasionally, but right now I just let the ill-named links go because any manual solution is not really practical. The toc entries are mostly being generated automatically from bibkeys and I can't realistically manage them manually so the bookmarks are a bit of a mess.

Comment: @cfr Ask a separate question and it will get more views and a better chance of getting a useful answer.